# How to prevent duplicate text while looping and retrieving data :

Tags: php, mysql

UBDATE : I found a better way : i created an other table that contains all tags

Hello i'm building a blog and i want to display all the used labels (in articles) ,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUghh.png

But the problem as you see in the picture there are a lot of duplicate tags and I want to prevent that, How ?? Help me !
here is my code :

```
<?php 

  do {

  if(strpos($row_Tags['tags'], " ")){ //Checks if the retrived tags contain any spaces
$array = explode(" ", $row_Tags['tags']); //Create an array of tags
foreach($array as $tag){

echo "<a href='article.php?tag=".$tag."'>".$tag."</a>";

}
}

} while ($row_Tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($Tags)); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Use `array_unique()`: `foreach(array_unique($array) as ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique)

```
$array=array_unique($row_Tags['tags']);
```

as your code you have to do it like this, it has to apply to array

```
$array=array_unique($array);
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i use it

Comment: before foreach you can use this

Comment: @Stormix: See my comment below your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_unique()` function to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Don't forget to mention he'd have to use `array_unique($array)` before the foreach loop